# Divide by zero error encountered while running a query

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

Below is the query I am trying to run using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio:

```
update [SG report MPD-4153] 
set [percent_paid] =  (try_convert(float, [Savings This Season])  * 100 / try_convert(float, [Savings 
Goal Amount]));
```

Comment: The error is telling you the problem here, what about the error don't you understand?

Comment: Wrap your denominator in a NULLIF()   i.e.  NULLIF( expr , 0 )

Comment: Also, does your column ending in `Goal Amount` *really* have a line break in it's name?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `nullif()` on the denominator:

```
update [SG report MPD-4153] 
    set [percent_paid] =  (try_convert(float, [Savings This Season])  * 100 
                           nullif(try_convert(float, [Savings Goal Amount], 0)
                          );
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume that `[Savings Goal Amount]` can sometimes be 0.  You'd have to determine what you want `[percent_paid]` to be set to in that case.  Assuming you're fine with it being set to `NULL` in that case, you can do this

```
update [SG report MPD-4153] 
   set [percent_paid] =  case when try_convert(float, [Savings Goal Amount] = 0 
                              then null
                              else (try_convert(float, [Savings This Season])  * 100 /
                                      try_convert(float, [Savings Goal Amount]))
                           end;
```

Or change the `then` clause if you want something other than `NULL`.